# using System.Collections.Generic in WinRT (windows app)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I am making a Windows 8 App to put on the store.

Some .NET assemblies seem to not be accessible (like some WPF graphics classes), while some ordinary, default assemblies (like S`ystem.Collections.Generic`) are no longer added by default.

I want to use the List class, but I'm afraid there's some hidden cost to using it (after all, why isn't it enabled by default on XAML apps?). Would my future users get an extra .NET DLL for WinRT they'll have to download? Will their computers explode in a loud, concussive blast? Ok, maybe that won't happen.

Am I bothering about nothing?

Comment: Should be fine according to MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the classes in [`System.Collections.Generic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) namespace are supported in Windows Store apps (the green suitcase icon in the first column). This means that they are availabe on Windws RT systems. So you don't need to worry about anything. There is no hidden cost or anything in using them.